# On iOS 10, how do you open the Suggested App on the Lock Screen?

Tags: ios, screen-lock

On the Lock Screen, Proactive Siri can suggest apps. If my iPhone detects I'm in the car, it correctly shows a Maps icon in the lower left corner on the lock screen.

Under iOS 9, you could swipe up to open that app.

How do you open the app in iOS 10? Swiping up doesn't work. 
Note: I am using a Force Touch enabled phone, but for completion's I'm also wondering how this works on a non-force touch phone.

Comment: Swiping up does work for me (7 plus, iOS 10.3.2) (Siri suggested the Mail app because I have it open on my Mac.) You *do* have to swipe it up from the corner where the app icon is shown.

Comment: (but that's no different from iOS 9)

Comment: It appears to be very finicky. You have to swipe up from the corner of the icon. And for some reason, it doesn't always go up, but just "bounces"